# vue3-html2pdf after generating pdf, content is not showing

Tags: vuejs3, jspdf, html-to-pdf, nuxt3

i am using nuxt3 in which i want to generate pdf with html elements so i am using package vue3-html2pdf. when i generate pdf it generates but blank pdf

here is code

```
<template>
    <div>
        <client-only>
            <vue3-html2pdf :show-layout="false" :float-layout="true" :enable-download="false" :preview-modal="true"
                :paginate-elements-by-height="1400" filename="hee_hee.pdf" :pdf-quality="2" :manual-pagination="false"
                pdf-format="letter" pdf-orientation="portrait" pdf-content-width="800px" @progress="onProgress($event)"
                @hasStartedGeneration="hasStartedGeneration()" @hasGenerated="hasGenerated($event)" ref="html2Pdf">
                <section slot="pdf-content">
                    <section class="pdf-item">
                        <h4>
                            Title
                        </h4>

                        <span>
                            Value
                        </span>
                    </section>
                    <section class="pdf-item">
                        <h4>
                            Title
                        </h4>

                        <span>
                            Value
                        </span>
                    </section>

                </section>
            </vue3-html2pdf>
        </client-only>
        <button v-on:click="generateReport">click</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue3Html2pdf from 'vue3-html2pdf'

export default {
    methods: {
        generateReport() {
            this.$refs.html2Pdf.generatePdf()
        },
    },

    components: {
        Vue3Html2pdf
    }
}
</script>


<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

The expected output is generated pdf with html content but returns blank pdf